# BigQuery JSON EXTRACT

Tags: google-bigquery

```html
[
   {
      "key":"expiry_date",
      "type":"date",
      "label":"Expiry Date",
      "required":false,
      "default_value":"2029-12-15"
   },
   {
      "key":"brand",
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Brand",
      "required":false,
      "default_value":"clipsal"
   }
]
```

Is there a way that I could extract the default_value of "expiry_date" in the nested JSON above? The data is under a column called attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(el, '$.default_value') AS default_value 
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(json)) el
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(el, '$.key') = 'expiry_date'
```

You can test above with sample / dummy data from y our question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '''
[
   {
      "key":"expiry_date",
      "type":"date",
      "label":"Expiry Date",
      "required":false,
      "default_value":"2029-12-15"
   },
   {
      "key":"brand",
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Brand",
      "required":false,
      "default_value":"clipsal"
   }
]  
  ''' json
)
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(el, '$.default_value') AS default_value 
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(json)) el
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(el, '$.key') = 'expiry_date'
```

with output

```
Row default_value    
1   2029-12-15
```

Depends on your real use case  - you can consider below variation

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *,
  (
    SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(el, '$.default_value') 
    FROM UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(json)) el
    WHERE JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(el, '$.key') = 'expiry_date'
  ) AS default_value
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Comment: the above works saved it on a separate view and call it on my main view. thanks, guys

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any of these functions described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions)? Maybe it can help.

Also, if the first element of the json array will be always what you want, you could use something like:

```
WITH test_table AS (
  SELECT "[{\"key\":\"expiry_date\",\"type\":\"date\",\"label\":\"Expiry Date\",\"required\":false,\"default_value\":\"2029-12-15\"},{\"key\":\"brand\",\"type\":\"text\",\"label\":\"Brand\",\"required\":false,\"default_value\":\"clipsal\"}]" AS json_text_field
)

SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_text_field, '$[0].default_value') FROM test_table
```

If the keys it's not always the first, you could use this instead:

```
WITH test_table AS (
  SELECT "[{\"key\":\"expiry_date\",\"type\":\"date\",\"label\":\"Expiry Date\",\"required\":false,\"default_value\":\"2029-12-15\"},{\"key\":\"brand\",\"type\":\"text\",\"label\":\"Brand\",\"required\":false,\"default_value\":\"clipsal\"}]" AS json_text_field
)

SELECT value FROM (
  SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_text_field, '$.key') AS id, JSON_EXTRACT(json_text_field, '$.default_value') AS value FROM test_table, UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(json_text_field, '$')) AS json_value
) WHERE id = '"expiry_date"'
```

Comment: that's obviously far from being generic solution as it assumes position of "key":"expiry_date" segment! what if it will be second or fifth, etc.

Comment: I know that, but it seems like it worked for him, anyway I added your scenario, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: this works as a temporary solution, I'll try the other suggestions. thanks guys